# What documentation exists for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

Tags: html, css, javascript, learning

PHP users have the [PHP.net docs](http://www.php.net/docs.php)
Ruby users have [Ruby-Doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/)
Python users have [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/)
jQuery users have [docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/)

All are considered go-to references when working within those environments.

But where's 'The Manual' for web designers and developers working with HTML, CSS, and (vanilla) JavaScript? What online, free, up-to-date, reliable, searchable, user-editable documentation should webmasters be using and referencing in their day-to-day work?

---

**Update:** I should have said that I'm aware of the W3C's Specifications and of the ECMAScript spec, but feel that they are better suited to browser vendors than they are to webmasters. From the HTML5 [specification intro](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/spec.html#audience):

> "...in places it sacrifices clarity for precision, and brevity for completeness..."

So, to rephrase my original question: **what clear, quick online references are available for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) docs really good, especially the [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) ones.

Answer (score 16):

The W3C handles the HTML and CSS specifications

[HTML 4 specification from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/)
[XHTML specification from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/)
[CSS 2.1 specifications from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/)
[HTML 5 specifications from the W3C (Working Draft)](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html)
[CSS 3 specifications (Working Draft)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#css3)

The official spec for JavaScript is the [EMCAscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) standard

[EMCA specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

**UPDATE**

I hope this is what you were looking for. Ipurposely didn't use the w3schools references because they are [known for having bad information in them](http://w3fools.com/).

[Sitepoint CSS reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css)
[Sitepoint HTML reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html)
[Sitepoint JavaScript reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript)

**UPDATE 2**

From Nick's comment: [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs)

Comment: Thanks, John. I've always felt that the W3C and ECMAscript specs were written more for browser vendors than for web developers. I've clarified my question above.

Comment: @Nick, Updated my answer. I think that is what you're looking for. If not let me know.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know about the Sitepoint docs, and just found out about the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) docs through the w3schools intervention link you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss) are the references for HTML and CSS. For Javascript it's the [ECMA specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). They meet all your requirements apart from user-editable. Is that good enough?

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I've clarified my question to show that I'm looking for more bite-size references than the official W3C specs.

Answer (score 1):

For HTML5, there are reduced versions of the spec specifically for web developers / authors:

- [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/)
- [WHATWG](http://developers.whatwg.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[DevDocs](http://devdocs.io/) pools documentation for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript together from multiple sources - including MDN – and puts them in one place in a searchable format. It's pretty handy.